# How to add Additional Text Before Post Title in Wordpress

Tags: php, html, wordpress

How do I add additional text without changing post title before title in WordPress for example the code is

```
the_title( '<h4 class="entry-title" ' . muvipro_itemprop_schema( 'name' ) . '>', '</h4>' );
```

and I want to add additional text before post title. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try this way?

```
<h4 class="entry-title <?php muvipro_itemprop_schema('name') ?>">
   your additional text
   <?php the_title(); ?>
</h4>
```